# How to sign-on with Google Identity Platform into different service of one company?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

We have many stand-alone services, such as **staff-portal.company.com** and "retail-portal.company.com," hosted in different subdomains. We are going to use a cloud identity platform as a single-sign-on system for the enterprise.

We can register multiple authorization domains in the Google Identity Platform console, but the audience of the return token audience is always firebase project-id which is not related to the requested domain. It means the tokens grant access to all services, which is unacceptable.

How can we set different audiences in the Google Identity-Platform token for each requested authorized domain?